# Computer extremely slow to start application but once it's ran, it works perfectly

Tags: hardware

I have a question for you guys. I am a programmer, I know a little bit about hardwire but this case is mysterious to me. I have money to buy new part but I want to know if its necessary. here it goes:

When I run ANY application (software) such as Filezila, any videogames, any broswers, it takes about 2 minutes until my computer runs it.

The parts that mindblow me in there is that once they are started, they run very fast and perfectly. My gear is quite good (better then average).

A friend of mine is an IT and told me it's probably my hard disc (C:) that is the problem.

I trust him but my D: disk is the same as my C: disk and I'm wondering should I put it my main disk with a backup of C:?

Is it even this? Help me on this one guys please, my computer is running very well except this part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try reloading everything, including the OS, from a hard disk reformat.

Comment: How? it's a PC by the way

Comment: Restarded it many times, repaired the disc using windows tool, sometimes, I cannot even write anything on the disc (download file from internet, etc)

Comment: Sadly this is off topic for this site, but **don't** buy anything until you've completely reinstalled the operating system after having reformatted your hard disks. If it's still slow after doing that then it's a hardware problem. Else it's software, and, from experience, it's much more likely to be a software issue.

Comment: im sorry, as you can see on my other account under programming I usually help the community but on this one I don't know where to seek help and really need to know the basics... could my harddisck (im french canadien this might not be the right worth, I mean C: and D:, be broken? Without losing anything, it's the only way to know right?

Comment: its my last resort before making backup and doing all the dirty work i just wish i could try something else before uninstalling everything

Comment: If you're a programmer then perhaps you could write something quick and dirty to test your disk i/o.

Comment: I'm a web programmer in fact but I could probably make a script for windows or find one online, good idea

Answer (score 1):

You likely have an old rotating hard drive instead of a SSD. Buy one. You want to know more? Have a look:

http://blog.codinghorror.com/building-a-pc-part-viii-iterating/

Comment: My laptob (the computre i'm talking about in this question is my tower, and I need it mostly for programming, gaming and photoshop (gaming games are RTS so I don't need PERFECT build), it has HDD but it's like 1 tera each disk (I have 2 disk), this is enough for me and I can deal with a small delay but for now it's too much... would switching my 2 hard disk would work?

Comment: My point is I agree with you about the SDD but is switching the part would be the only way? it worked perfectly before

Comment: When it worked well before, your problem may of course also be of different kind. Maybe your hard-disk is dying. Or there is a problem with your operation system.